# How to change the IdType in item_lookup from ASIN to ISBN?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm using the [Amazon Product Advertising API (amazon-ecs) Ruby library](https://github.com/jugend/amazon-ecs) - how can I change the `IdType` in `item_lookup` from ASIN to ISBN?

Doing something like this:

```
Amazon::Ecs.item_lookup('9781934356166', :response_group => 'ItemAttributes,Images')
```

Not sure where to change the option for the IdType to ISBN.  I've tried putting it several places.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just monkey patched the gem's source and created a new method called item_lookup_isbn that was identical to the item_lookup except the asin part.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [Amazon Product Advertising API (formerly ECS) docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/), it seems you need to specify an IdType parameter of 'ISBN'. I've never used this particular gem, but I'm guessing the request would look something like this:

```
Amazon::Ecs.item_lookup('9781934356166', :response_group => 'ItemAttributes,Images', :id_type => 'ISBN')
```

According to the docs "All IdTypes except ASINx require a SearchIndex to be specified" so you'll most likely need to do this:

```
Amazon::Ecs.item_lookup('9781934356166', :response_group => 'ItemAttributes,Images', :id_type => 'ISBN', :search_index => 'Books')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried that + as many versions of the symbol :id_type I could think of.  Instead, I just monkey-patched it :D